# Does System Integrity Protection have any effects on OS's besides Mac OS?

Tags: security, dual-boot, sip

If I understand correctly, SIP is a security feature that protects certain folders on Mac OS from modification, even by root users.

I don't know how it works on a low level though, and I was wondering if enabling/disabling it has any positive/negative effects on other OS's installed on a Macbook, such as Windows or Linux distros. So, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, SIP is only applied within a macOS partition. You can have a look at `/System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf` to see which folders and files get protected by default.

Answer (score 1):

[SIP is a macOS feature/function](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) that's applicable to El Capitan and later; it's not dependent on the Mac hardware.

If you're not running macOS, there's no SIP.